# Access Jenkins credentials from within plugins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm following the documentation here https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/blob/master/docs/consumer.adoc

Specifically this example:

```java
public ListBoxModel doFillCredentialsIdItems(
        @AncestorInPath Item item,
        @QueryParameter String credentialsId,
        ... (1)
        ) {
  StandardListBoxModel result = new StandardListBoxModel();
  if (item == null) {
    if (!Jenkins.getActiveInstance().hasPermission(Jenkins.ADMINISTER)) {
      return result.includeCurrentValue(credentialsId); (2)
    }
  } else {
    if (!item.hasPermission(Item.EXTENDED_READ)
        && !item.hasPermission(CredentialsProvider.USE_ITEM)) {
      return result.includeCurrentValue(credentialsId); (2)
    }
  }
  return result
    .includeEmptySelection() (3)
    .includeMatchingAs(...) (4)
    .includeCurrentValue(credentialsId); (5)
}
```

1. Include any additional contextual parameters that you need in order to refine the credentials list. For example, if the credentials will be used to connect to a remote server, you might include the server URL form element as a @QueryParameter so that the domain requirements can be built from that URL.
2. We protect against fully populating the drop-down list for users that have no ability to actually make a selection. This is also useful in preventing unwanted requests being made to an external credentials store.
3. If it is valid for the user to select no credentials, then include the empty selection.
4. We need to include the matching credentials. In some cases you may have disjoint unions of credentials, in which case you can call this method multiple times, the first credential added for any given ID wins.
5. If you include the current value then the form configuration will remain unchanged in the event that the backing credential is removed. An alternative is to let the form "magically" select a new credential, but typically this will be the wrong credential. The recommendation is to just add the "non-existing" credential and have form validation report the error

However, I'm getting stuck at step 4 in the example, what should I do here? I've tried looking at the other plugins to see how they implement this but I'm get lost quickly. Is there a simple demo that shows how this works?

Here's my code which is based on the Jenkins "Hello World Example".

```java
package io.jenkins.plugins.sample;

import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.*;
import hudson.Launcher;
import hudson.Extension;
import hudson.FilePath;
import hudson.model.*;
import hudson.util.FormValidation;
import hudson.tasks.Builder;
import hudson.tasks.BuildStepDescriptor;
import hudson.util.ListBoxModel;
import jenkins.model.Jenkins;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.CredentialsProvider;
import org.kohsuke.stapler.*;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;
import jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep;
import org.jenkinsci.Symbol;

public class HelloWorldBuilder extends Builder implements SimpleBuildStep {

    private final String name;
    private final String credentials;
    private boolean useFrench;
    private final String tppurl;

    @DataBoundConstructor
    public HelloWorldBuilder(String name, String tppurl, String credentials) {
        this.name = name;
        this.tppurl = tppurl;
        this.credentials = credentials;
    }

    @DataBoundSetter
    public void setUseFrench(boolean useFrench) {
        this.useFrench = useFrench;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getTppurl() {
        return tppurl;
    }

    public String getCredentials() {
        return credentials;
    }

    public boolean isUseFrench() {
        return useFrench;
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(Run<?, ?> run, FilePath workspace, Launcher launcher, TaskListener listener) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        if (useFrench) {
            listener.getLogger().println("Bonjour, " + name + "!");
        } else {
            listener.getLogger().println("Hello, " + name + tppurl + "! " );
        }
    }

    @Symbol("greet")
    @Extension
    public static final class DescriptorImpl extends BuildStepDescriptor<Builder> {

        public FormValidation doCheckName(@QueryParameter String value, @QueryParameter boolean useFrench)
                throws IOException, ServletException {
            if (value.length() == 0)
                return FormValidation.error(Messages.HelloWorldBuilder_DescriptorImpl_errors_missingName());
            if (value.length() < 4)
                return FormValidation.warning(Messages.HelloWorldBuilder_DescriptorImpl_warnings_tooShort());
            if (!useFrench && value.matches(".*[éáàç].*")) {
                return FormValidation.warning(Messages.HelloWorldBuilder_DescriptorImpl_warnings_reallyFrench());
            }
            return FormValidation.ok();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isApplicable(Class<? extends AbstractProject> aClass) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public String getDisplayName() {
            return Messages.HelloWorldBuilder_DescriptorImpl_DisplayName();
        }

    }

//This is the credentials bit

    public ListBoxModel doFillCredentialsIdItems(
            @AncestorInPath Item item,
            @QueryParameter String credentialsId,
        ) {
        StandardListBoxModel result = new StandardListBoxModel();
        if (item == null) {
            if (!Jenkins.getActiveInstance().hasPermission(Jenkins.ADMINISTER)) {
                return result.includeCurrentValue(credentialsId); 
            }
        } else {
            if (!item.hasPermission(Item.EXTENDED_READ)
                    && !item.hasPermission(CredentialsProvider.USE_ITEM)) {
                return result.includeCurrentValue(credentialsId); 
            }
        }
        return result
                .includeEmptySelection() 
                .includeMatchingAs(STUCK HERE!!!!!) 
                .includeCurrentValue(credentialsId); 
    }


// end credentials


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an updated info on the page that offers more details about how it should be used

In the com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.AbstractIdCredentialsListBoxModel class the method is declared as:

```
    /**
 * Adds the ids of the specified credential type that are available to the specified context as the specified
 * authentication with the specified domain requirements and match the specified filter.
 *
 * @param authentication     the authentication to search with
 * @param context            the context to add credentials from.
 * @param type               the base class of the credentials to add.
 * @param domainRequirements the domain requirements.
 * @param matcher            the filter to apply to the credentials.
 * @return {@code this} for method chaining.
 * @see CredentialsProvider#listCredentials(Class, Item, Authentication, List, CredentialsMatcher)
 * @since 2.1.0
 */
public AbstractIdCredentialsListBoxModel<T, C> includeMatchingAs(@NonNull Authentication authentication,
                                                                 @NonNull Item context,
                                                                 @NonNull Class<? extends C> type,
                                                                 @NonNull
                                                                         List<DomainRequirement> domainRequirements,
                                                                 @NonNull CredentialsMatcher matcher) {
    addMissing(CredentialsProvider.listCredentials(type, context, authentication, domainRequirements, matcher));
    return this;
}

/**
 * Adds the ids of the specified credential type that are available to the specified context as the specified
 * authentication with the specified domain requirements and match the specified filter.
 *
 * @param authentication     the authentication to search with
 * @param context            the context to add credentials from.
 * @param type               the base class of the credentials to add.
 * @param domainRequirements the domain requirements.
 * @param matcher            the filter to apply to the credentials.
 * @return {@code this} for method chaining.
 * @see CredentialsProvider#listCredentials(Class, ItemGroup, Authentication, List, CredentialsMatcher)
 * @since 2.1.0
 */
public AbstractIdCredentialsListBoxModel<T, C> includeMatchingAs(@NonNull Authentication authentication,
                                                                 @NonNull ItemGroup context,
                                                                 @NonNull Class<? extends C> type,
                                                                 @NonNull
                                                                         List<DomainRequirement> domainRequirements,
                                                                 @NonNull CredentialsMatcher matcher) {
    addMissing(CredentialsProvider.listCredentials(type, context, authentication, domainRequirements, matcher));
    return this;
}
```